# Button won't allow me to add data into ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to send 3 different Jtextfields to an ArrayList, but I get error:

```
"forms" cannot be resolved in this line: forms.add(form);
```

Here is the whole button code that sends the data:

```
// button add
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Product form = new Product();
            form.date = textDate.getText();
            form.fac = textFac.getText();
            form.total = Long.parseLong(textTotal.getText());
            forms.add(form);
        }
    });
```

The ArrayList is called "forms":

```
 package dao;


     import entities.*;
     import java.util.*;
     import javax.swing.JTextField;
     import java.text.*;
      import javaapplication1.*;

     public class ProductModel{

   public List<Product> findAll(){
       try {
           List<Product> forms = new ArrayList<Product>();
           JTextField textDate;
           JTextField textFecha;
           JTextField textTotal;
           return forms;
         } catch (Exception e){
             return null;
         }
       }

   }
```

So, I dont really know why `forms.add(form);` doesnt work. And I do have the `import thePackageOfthearraylist.*;` but still, I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: `forms` is local to the `findAll` method, you'll need to make it global to the containing class if both `addActionListener` functionality and `findAll` are in the same class that is, else consider creating a `getter` method to the `forms` list if they're in different classes.

Comment: okay, they are both in the same class... what do you mean by "findAll" how do I put it, in the button right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create forms variable of type `java.util.ArrayList`. Make this variable global or local and initialize it with `ProductModel.finalAll` method.

```
List<Product> forms=new ArrayList<Product>();
// button add
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Product form = new Product();
            form.date = textDate.getText();
            form.fac = textFac.getText();
            form.total = Long.parseLong(textTotal.getText());
            forms.add(form);
        }
    });
```

global means at class level and local means variable created in method

Comment: How can I do that, can you give me an example? I tried searching on google (how to set a global variable), and I found one way of doing it is by setting the class to `static` but it doesn't  work. could you explain, please?

Comment: post all related classes and better runnable code. At first learn java core, mvc pattern then go to swing

Answer (score 0):

To use the arraylist "forms" inside the actionPerformed method the list has to be defined and initialized in the local scope of the actionPerformed method or defined in the global scope of the class containing the actionPerformed method.